# Styled components not applying styles

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this 2 styled components

```
  export const Icon = styled.svg`
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: black;
`

export const Dots = styled.div`
  border: 2px solid green !imporant;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;



  ${Icon}: hover {
    background:black;
  }
  
  }
```

`

I want to display `Icon` on the hover of this div but i dont understand why it is not working,
Any suggestions please?

Comment: In the code above `hover` is applied to `Icon` instead of div.

Comment: I tried like this but did not work `&:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    ${Icon};
  } ` @AntonBakinowsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code except on hover you don't change the color from its default value `black`

```
const Icon = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
`;

export const Dots = styled.div`
  ${Icon}:hover {
    background: red;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Dots>
      <Icon />
    </Dots>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-react-template-forked-nzwm8

Answer (score 0):

You should place the hover styles inside the icon

```
  export const Icon = styled.svg`
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: black;

  &:hover {
    background: black;
  }
```